# Convert column type INTERVAL to cell type in MS Excel via ODBC

Tags: excel, postgresql, types, odbc, sqldatatypes

I would like to import INTERVAL data type via PostgreSQL ODBC driver to MS Excel sheet. The cell type becomes General. Is it possible to import the data type somehow so the cell type is Time?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to cast the interval to `TIME` in your query, e.g.:

```
SELECT t.duration::TIME FROM my_table t;
```

but this will only work for intervals less than 24 hours. For longer intervals you may use the duration in seconds like

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t.duration) FROM my_table t;
```

which gives you a floating point value of type `DOUBLE PRECISION`.

Comment: I agree, this is an option. But I was asking if there is a possibility how to import INTERVAL type itself. But I guess ODBC does not support this type so the only option is to convert it to different time units.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr: You may also cast the interval to text. But I see no other option.